# ASP NET C# System.Windows.Form does not exist in the class or namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

ASP NET C#  using System.Windows.Form namespace producce error "The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the class or namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

I test it with WinXP ver 2002 SP3, 
MS Visual Studio Microsoft Development Enviroment 2002 ver 7, framework 2.0;
and with
Win7Professional, MS Visual Studio 2008 Express, framework 3.5 (inside Win7?)

Comment: this is happening at compile time, right?

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms in the visual studio by right-clicking the references or project in the solution explorer.

But I could not figure out what it has got to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create web or desktop application? You can't use both within a single project.
If you want to create a new desktop application, you can do it by selecting:

> File -> New -> Project -> Visual C# ->
>   Windows - Windows Forms Application

Comment: You can use both just fine. Just add a reference to System.Windows.Forms and go with it. Whether this is a good idea or not is an entirely different question :)

Comment: Yes, you can create new windows forms controls from code behind, but VS won't let you to use any Windows Forms templates inside a web project :)